Is there any way to add custom check in policy to azure DevOps server 2022 programmatically?
In our office, we defined a couple of custom check in changes rules. So when a developer want's to check in changes, if these rules don't satisfy, we should show warnings and prevent developer to check in changes. Indeed, I need a before check in service hook event or create custom check in policy to control my custom check in rules are satisfied or not. I didn't find any service hook for that. Could I define custom policy for Azure DevOps Server 2022? Or is there any other way to control check in custom rules?
I dont find any documentation for create cutom policy in azure DevOps server 2022. I found it but I dont want to register policy manually for each developer.

Hi @MaryamKhaliji, Good day to you and have you got a chance to check my answer below on the current limitation to use TFVC check-in policies? We are still limited by the built-in feature, but hope the information answers your query in this post. Thx and cheers.

Hi @MaryamKhaliji, Based on the release note, I am afraid the TFVC feature of Azure DevOps is going to be deprecated. Please consider migrating repos to GIT, since as of now we do not have a date planned for deprecation and we will have plenty of time to make adjustments if/when this is set to be done.

According to the statement this Azure DevOps document on TFVC check-in policies,

You can set Visual Studio check-in policies through Team Explorer as documented in this article, the tf.exe configure command, or through registry keys declared in the pkgdef of a Visual Studio extension.


Policies only apply to a single installation of Visual Studio on your computer. If you have multiple installations of Visual Studio, you need to set the check-in policy on each installation.

Unfortunately, this will not change as TFVC is deprecated and no longer receives feature updates. See the release note that is phasing out TFVC.
For this, please consider migrating repos from TFVC to GIT, since as of now there is not a date planned for deprecation and we will have plenty of time to make adjustments if/when this is set to be done.
